# Filter list view - comparing custom user lookup to logged in user

Tags: list-view

I have a custom object and a custom field in that, which is lookup to user called 'Item Owner'. This custom field was required because the object is a child in master detail but required to have a namesake owner for each record. I want to filter the list view of this object such that it shows only those records in which the owner field equals to the logged in user. Is this possible?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a formula field (IsItemOwnerLoggedInUser?) with return type as checkbox and set it to true for currently logged in user.

```
Item_Owner__c == $User.Id
```

Create a new view and in the filter criteria, enter **"IsItemOwnerLoggedInUser"**  *equals* **True**

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can filter by running user, vote up this idea here. [VOTE](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrlpAAC) One way would be to create a formula field that compared the running user ID to that field and resulted in a check box, being true. Then you could have the formula field like "my record" equals true in the criteria.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new view say **My View** and select the highlighted radio button it will automatically show only those record where owner is the current logged in user.
[image]